# Nested Enumerated list with different left margins in LATEx

Tags: lists

I am trying to create template for nested enumerated lists. The label of first list is aligned with left margin of the page (use environment FirstList). Then the subsequent nested lists is indented by some space (use environment SecondList). To indent the nested lists, I am using adjustwidth, however, it results in an extra pair of brackets. Please see figure below.

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 % Packages used in template.
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{changepage}
 \usepackage{etoolbox}

 % Set left, right, top, and bottom margins of the paper.
 \usepackage[a4paper, left = 1.5in, right = 0.70in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 2.2in]{geometry}
 \voffset = 0.15in
 \headsep = 31pt
 \topmargin = -48pt

 % Create new environments for listings
 \setlist[enumerate]{wide, align=left, topsep = 0in, parsep = 0.24in, partopsep = 0in, itemsep = 0in, labelindent = 0in, labelsep = 0.36in}
 \newenvironment{FirstList}[1][]{ \begingroup \let \olditem \item
     \renewcommand \item {\olditem
     \ifnum\value{enumi} > 9
     \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}
     \fi
     \ifnum\value{enumi} > 99
     \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}
     \fi
     \ifnum\value{enumi} > 999
     \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}
     \fi
     }
     \begin{enumerate}[#1] } {\end{enumerate} \endgroup}

 \newenvironment{SecondList}{ \begin{adjustwidth}{0.48in}{0in}
     \begin{enumerate}}{ \end{enumerate} \end{adjustwidth}}

 \begin{document}
     \begin{FirstList}

        \item This template is made for A4 page size. I will try to extend this point into more than two lines.

        \item In this template,

        \begin{SecondList}
            \item Left margin is $\mathrm{1.5}$ in.

            \item Right margin is $\mathrm{0.7}$ in.

        \end{SecondList}

        \item This is another enumerated point.

         \begin{SecondList}
            \item This is another enumerated point.

            \item This is another enumerated point.
        \end{SecondList}

         \item This is another enumerated point.

    \end{FirstList}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Question No. 1- How to remove the extra brakets?

Question No. 2- Is it possible to create a single environment which can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave you the details of the margins, which are not very clear from your question. In particular, add the desired values for `rightmargin`.

You *can* and *should* use a single environment for this and not overload `enumerate`.

I changed some of the values for `geometry`, first of all because `\voffset` should never be used for positioning the text block, nor you should modify `\topmargin`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Packages used in template.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Set left, right, top, and bottom margins of the paper.
\usepackage[
  showframe,
  a4paper,
  left = 1.5in,
  right = 0.70in,
  top = 1in,
  bottom = 1.05in,
  headsep=31pt,
]{geometry}
%\voffset = 0.15in  %%%% <---- NO
%\headsep = 31pt    %%%% <---- NO
%\topmargin = -48pt %%%% <---- NO

% Create new environments for listings
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[mylist]{
  wide,
  align=left,
  topsep = 0in,
  parsep = 0.24in,
  partopsep = 0in,
  itemsep = 0in,
  labelsep = 0in,
  itemindent=0.5in,
  labelindent = -0.5in,
  labelwidth=0.5in,
}
\setlist[mylist,1]{leftmargin=0in,label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[mylist,2]{leftmargin=0.5in,label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[mylist,3]{leftmargin=1in,label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}

  \item This template is made for A4 page size. I will try to extend this point 
        into more than two lines.

  \item In this template,

  \begin{mylist}
    \item Left margin is $\mathrm{1.5}$ in.

    \item Right margin is $\mathrm{0.7}$ in.

  \end{mylist}

  \item This is another enumerated point.

  \begin{mylist}
    \item This is another enumerated point.

    \item This is another enumerated point.
  \end{mylist}

  \item This is another enumerated point.

\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `SecondList` environment to

```
\newenvironment{SecondList}
  {\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1in, rightmargin=0in, labelindent=*]}
  {\end{enumerate}}
```

works.

- The `leftmargin=1in, rightmargin=0in` corresponds to your original `\begin{adjustwidth}{0.48in}{0in}`. Here I use a larger `leftmargin` since you have used a rather large `labelsep = 0.36in`.
- The `labelindent=*` forces the re-computation.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Packages used in template.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Set left, right, top, and bottom margins of the paper.
\usepackage[a4paper, left = 1.5in, right = 0.70in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 2.2in, showframe]{geometry}

% Create new environments for listings
\setlist[enumerate]{wide, align=left, topsep = 0in, parsep = 0.24in, partopsep = 0in, itemsep = 0in, labelindent = 0in, labelsep = 0.36in}

\newenvironment{FirstList}[1][]{ \begingroup \let \olditem \item
   \renewcommand \item {\olditem
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 9
   \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}
   \fi
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 99
   \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}
   \fi
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 999
   \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}
   \fi
   }
   \begin{enumerate}[#1] } {\end{enumerate} \endgroup}

\newenvironment{SecondList}
  {\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1in, rightmargin=0in, labelindent=*]}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
   \begin{FirstList}

      \item This template is made for A4 page size. I will try to extend this point into more than two lines.

      \item In this template,

      \begin{SecondList}
          \item Left margin is $\mathrm{1.5}$ in.

          \item Right margin is $\mathrm{0.7}$ in.

      \end{SecondList}

      \item This is another enumerated point.

      \begin{SecondList}
          \item This is another enumerated point.

          \item This is another enumerated point.
      \end{SecondList}

      \item This is another enumerated point.

    \end{FirstList}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of modified example]

---

By the way,

- Setting `\voffset` to non-zero value is not recommended and totally avoidable. Use `geometry` options and use them only is enough.
- `\setlist` can set different styles for different levels of list, for example `\setlist[enumerate, 2]{...}`. Hence your `FistList` and `SecondList` environments are avoidable as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible that the label of a nested list is directly below the text of parent list?

Comment: +1 For the fix but as you say at the end `enumitem` provides better tools for doing this

Comment: @AliBaig You mean, you want to have "no vertical skip before (and maybe also after) nested list"?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ The label (a) of the SecondList and the text of item (1) should be at the same distance from the margin of the page.

Comment: @AliBaig Just remove options of `enumerate` env used inside the definition of `SecondList` env.

Answer (score 1):

As muzimuzhi said at the end of his nice post, the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package provides better tools for doing this sort of thing. You can use `\setlist[enumerate,1]{...}` to set the parameters that you want for the first level of an `enumerate` environment and then `\setlist[enumerate,2]{...}` for the second level etc. Hence, following the suggestion muzimuzhi you can set up your `enumerate` environments with:

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
  wide,
  align=left,
  topsep = 0in,
  parsep = 0.24in,
  partopsep = 0in,
  itemsep = 0in,
  labelindent = 0in,
  labelsep = 0.36in,
}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
  leftmargin=1in,
  rightmargin=0in,
  labelindent=*
}
```

This still leaves your custom `\item` command. Rather than defining this each time the `FirstList` environment is used I would move this code into the preamble as:

```
\let\olditem\item
\newcommand\MyItem {\olditem
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 9   \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}\fi
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 99  \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}\fi
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 999 \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}\fi
}
```

and to get `enumerate` to use this you can add `before=\let\item\MyItem`
 to the `\setlist` command. Putting this in place, you can drop your `FirstList` and `SecondList` environments and just use `enumerate` (or you could, instead, define a new list environment with `\newlist`), so  your MWE becomes

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Packages used in template.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Set left, right, top, and bottom margins of the paper.
\usepackage[a4paper, left = 1.5in, right = 0.70in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 2.2in, showframe]{geometry}

\let\olditem\item
\newcommand\MyItem {\olditem
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 9   \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}\fi
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 99  \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}\fi
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 999 \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}\fi
}

% Create new environments for listings
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
  wide,
  align=left,
  topsep = 0in,
  parsep = 0.24in,
  partopsep = 0in,
  itemsep = 0in,
  labelindent = 0in,
  labelsep = 0.36in,
  before=\let\item\MyItem
}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
  leftmargin=1in,
  rightmargin=0in,
  labelindent=*
}

\begin{document}

   \begin{enumerate}
      \item This template is made for A4 page size. I will try to extend
      this point into more than two lines.

      \item In this template,

      \begin{enumerate}
          \item Left margin is $\mathrm{1.5}$ in.
          \item Right margin is $\mathrm{0.7}$ in.
      \end{enumerate}

      \item This is another enumerated point.

      \begin{enumerate}
          \item This is another enumerated point.
          \item This is another enumerated point.
      \end{enumerate}

      \item This is another enumerated point.

    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

and the output is exactly the same as that in muzimuzhi's nice answer:

[image]

**Edit**

As far as I can see this does work properly with nesting? For example,
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    % Packages used in template.
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

```
% Set left, right, top, and bottom margins of the paper.
\usepackage[a4paper, left = 1.5in, right = 0.70in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 2.2in, showframe]{geometry}

\let\olditem\item
\newcommand\MyItem {\olditem
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 9   \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}\fi
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 99  \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}\fi
   \ifnum\value{enumi} > 999 \setlength\hskip{-0.14in}\fi
}

% Create new environments for listings
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
  wide,
  align=left,
  topsep = 0in,
  parsep = 0.24in,
  partopsep = 0in,
  itemsep = 0in,
  labelindent = 0in,
  labelsep = 0.36in,
  before=\let\item\MyItem
}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
  leftmargin=1in,
  rightmargin=0in,
  labelindent=*
}

\begin{document}

   \begin{enumerate}
      \item This template is made for A4 page size. I will try to extend
      this point into more than two lines.

      \item In this template,

      \begin{enumerate}
          \item This template is made for A4 page size. I will try to extend
          this point into more than two lines.
          \item Left margin is $\mathrm{1.5}$ in.
          \item Right margin is $\mathrm{0.7}$ in.
      \end{enumerate}

      \item This is another enumerated point.

      \begin{enumerate}
          \item This is another enumerated point.
          \item This template is made for A4 page size. I will try to extend
          this point into more than two lines.
          \item This is another enumerated point.
      \end{enumerate}

      \item This is another enumerated point.

    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is a little problem with your template. The second line in any nested level does not start below its label. For example, try

Comment: @AliBaig As far as I can see this works? See my edit.